# How to Properly Pass Marketo Form ID in Munchkin API

Tags: php, drupal-7, marketo

We're converting our Marketo forms from using the standalone forms that you build in Marketo to using the Munchkin API to pass data to Marketo from our Drupal website. We base a number of triggers on the form name, and all our user data seems to be passing in correctly, but we can't seem to get Marketo to recognize which form has been submitted. So my question is: how do I ensure Marketo recognizes the form being submitted? In the Marketo forms, it seems that formid handles this functionality, but passing that field doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Munchkin API doesn't permit passing of form id, and won't trigger the fills out form trigger.  I'd suggest looking at this method as an alternative, which would let you trigger fills out form as you like: http://developers.marketo.com/blog/make-a-marketo-form-submission-in-the-background/